# Python sort json array keys

Tags: python, json, sorting

i have this json

```
{"1": {"ask": "232,40", "bid": "232,30", "name": "adidas AG"}, 
"10": {"ask": "8,314", "bid": "8,313", "name": "Deutsche Bank AG"}, 
"11": {"ask": "160,15", "bid": "160,10", "name": "Deutsche B\u00f6rse AG"}, 
"12": {"ask": "32,57", "bid": "32,56", "name": "Deutsche Post AG"}, 
"13": {"ask": "14,94", "bid": "14,935", "name": "Deutsche Telekom AG"}, 
"14": {"ask": "39,97", "bid": "39,96", "name": "Deutsche Wohnen SE"}, 
"15": {"ask": "10,115", "bid": "10,11", "name": "E.ON SE"}, 
"16": {"ask": "76,06", "bid": "76,04", "name": "Fresenius Medical Care KGaA"}, 
"17": {"ask": "43,87", "bid": "43,85", "name": "Fresenius SE & Co. KGaA"}, 
"18": {"ask": "47,66", "bid": "47,65", "name": "HeidelbergCement AG"}, 
"19": {"ask": "83,94", "bid": "83,92", "name": "Henkel AG & Co. KGaA VZ"}, 
"2": {"ask": "180,38", "bid": "180,36", "name": "Allianz SE"}, 
"20": {"ask": "20,80", "bid": "20,79", "name": "Infineon Technologies AG"}, 
"21": {"ask": "188,15", "bid": "188,10", "name": "Linde PLC"}, 
"22": {"ask": "103,20", "bid": "103,15", "name": "Merck KGaA"}, 
"23": {"ask": "155,35", "bid": "155,25", "name": "MTU Aero Engines AG"}, 
"24": {"ask": "228,20", "bid": "228,00", "name": "M\u00fcnchener R\u00fcckvers.-Ges. AG"}, 
"25": {"ask": "31,19", "bid": "31,18", "name": "RWE AG"}, 
"26": {"ask": "123,14", "bid": "123,10", "name": "SAP SE"}, 
"27": {"ask": "103,98", "bid": "103,96", "name": "Siemens AG"}, 
"28": {"ask": "134,36", "bid": "134,30", "name": "Volkswagen AG VZ"}, 
"29": {"ask": "55,14", "bid": "55,12", "name": "Vonovia SE"}, 
"3": {"ask": "49,95", "bid": "49,94", "name": "BASF SE"}, 
"30": {"ask": "5,36", "bid": "5,36", "name": "Wirecard AG"}, 
"4": {"ask": "66,14", "bid": "66,13", "name": "Bayer AG"}, 
"5": {"ask": "56,47", "bid": "56,46", "name": "Bayerische Motoren Werke AG"}, 
"6": {"ask": "101,65", "bid": "101,60", "name": "Beiersdorf AG"}, 
"7": {"ask": "87,52", "bid": "87,48", "name": "Continental AG"}, 
"8": {"ask": "34,25", "bid": "34,23", "name": "Covestro AG"}, 
"9": {"ask": "35,875", "bid": "35,87", "name": "Daimler AG"}, 
"datum": "30.06.2020", 
"zeit": "12:51:01"}
```

The keys are in a wrong order. I want the order 1,2,3...  and i dont want 1,10,11....2,20...3,30... etc.

How do i sort this json? I tried `json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True)` but this is not the result i want.

Comment: The keys in JSON are *strings*, they're sorted lexicographically.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some padding to the keys to get them to sort "numerically":

```
print(sorted(data.keys(), key=lambda key: key.zfill(2)))
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', 'datum', 'zeit']
```

And to reassemble the json:

```
print(json.dumps(dict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[0].zfill(2)))))
```

Output:

```
{"1": {"ask": "232,40", "bid": "232,30", "name": "adidas AG"}, "2": {"ask": "180,38", "bid": "180,36", "name": "Allianz SE"}, "3": {"ask": "49,95", "bid": "49,94", "name": "BASF SE"}...
```

Comment: This produces random results on my system.

Comment: What version of Python are you on?  Does it produce consistent results if you remove `json.dumps()` ?

Comment: When running under Python 3.4.2 (default, Sep 16 2019, 19:58:00) the first line produces correct output, the second line you wrote produces random results. When running under Python 2.7.9 (default, Sep 16 2019, 18:29:54) there is no random results, but it starts with index "datum" (date) and next index is "24" etc. Wrong order under python2 and random order under python3 on my raspberry pi 2

Comment: Ok, Python 3.6+ dictionaries maintain key insertion order so what you're saying for 3.4/2.7 makes sense.  We can try this: `from collections import OrderedDict` and replace our call to `dict()` with `OrderedDict()` here: `print(json.dumps(OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[0].zfill(2)))))`

Comment: Thx, this works, but in the meantime i solved it by converting indices to int(). I'll try to upgrade my python version :)